# SolrException: Internal Server Error

Tags: search, indexing, solr

I am working on Solr in my application. I am using *apache-solr-solrj-1.4.0.jar*.

When I try to call `add(SolrInputDocument doc)` from `CommonsHttpSolrServer`, I am getting the following exception:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Internal Server Error
>   Internal Server Error
>   at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:424)
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:243)
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
>           at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.add(SolrServer.java:64)

Can anyone please help me to resolve this problem?

The following are the attributes in *solrconfig.xml*:

```
<lockType>native</lockType>
<unlockOnStartup>false</unlockOnStartup>
<reopenReaders>true</reopenReaders>
```

---

I am getting the following exception in the solr server logs:

> 24 May, 2010 2:51:22 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>   SEVERE: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler$4.postCommit(ReplicationHandler.java:922)
>           at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.callPostCommitCallbacks(UpdateHandler.java:78)
>           at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:411)
>           at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:85)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerUtils.handleCommit(RequestHandlerUtils.java:107)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:48)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:347)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>           at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

---

> INFO: {} 0 1039
>   24 May, 2010 2:52:29 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>   SEVERE: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@./solr/data/index/lucene-be18de26b941317e71dc59f9e5ba63c4-write.lock
>           at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:85)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.init(IndexWriter.java:1545)
>           at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.(IndexWriter.java:1402)
>           at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.(SolrIndexWriter.java:190)
>           at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler.createMainIndexWriter(UpdateHandler.java:98)
>           at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.openWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:173)
>           at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:220)
>           at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:139)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:69)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:54)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:131)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1316)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:338)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:347)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>           at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am very unsure, but in this thread

http://www.mail-archive.com/solr-user@lucene.apache.org/msg08048.html

they recommend to use

```
<unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>
```

and

```
<lockType>simple</lockType>
```

I think this should be safe as long as you access the index through solr or solrj (not though lucene!).

Any other ideas?

Comment: Where does this  <unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>
and

<lockType>simple</lockType>   have to be added for spring boot?

Answer (score 6):

I have set following in my solrconfig.xml and it works.

```
<lockType>simple</lockType>
<unlockOnStartup>true</unlockOnStartup>
```

Also, set following to avoid write lock exceptions on index directory:

```
<maxFieldLength>10000</maxFieldLength>
<writeLockTimeout>60000</writeLockTimeout>
<commitLockTimeout>60000</commitLockTimeout>
```

Comment: Although this seems to be true, ```unlockOnStartup``` seems to assumes you are not locking and setting the timeouts should have no effect at all. At least based on the documentation in the solrconfig.xml

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/IndexConfig+in+SolrConfig :  The maxFieldLength parameter was removed in Solr 4. If restricting the length of fields is important to you, you can get similar behavior with the LimitTokenCountFactory, which can be defined for the fields you'd like to limit. For example, <filter class="solr.LimitTokenCountFilterFactory" maxTokenCount="10000"/> would limit the field to 10,000 characters.[/code]

Comment: I was getting same error. After I added <writeLockTimeout>30000</writeLockTimeout> to solrConfig.xml and solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SolrJ client does not give you the actual error. Try looking at the solr server logs which should be located under tomcat or jetty (or whatever runs solr).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupt index or busy lock file..  I had something similar and restarting worked, oddly enough.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from failing to remove write.lock file after some update actions. Removing the write.lock in the core's data/index folder will solve this problem temporarily and regain updating action. I know using post.jar to update has more bad luck to cause this problem, whereas url with stream.body rarely cause this problem. Karussel's answer did improves the situation but seems not solve it at all. I doubt it comes from some design issue of Solr. Hope Solr 4 has solved this problem. Also one can refer to the answer in this question: [how-to-solve-the-lock-obtain-timed-out-when-using-solr-plainly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517348/how-to-solve-the-lock-obtain-timed-out-when-using-solr-plainly)